# What does 外国人のように imply in this sentence?

Tags: pragmatics

My friend is reading a book, and it contains the following sentence:

> すると、高畑は**外国人のように**両手を上げる仕草をした。

Why does this say `外国人のように`?  Are foreigners known for a particular gesture in which we raise both our arms...?  When I read this sentence, I feel like I'm missing some implication that's required for it to make sense.

I have a picture of the page this sentence is from, in case further context is helpful:

[image: Picture of the relevant page]

Comment: [[ Are foreigners known for a particular gesture in which we raise both our arms...? ]] - A [double deuce](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Double%20Deuce) maybe?

Comment: shrugだと思います http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/187366/187366,1219414675,1/stock-photo-young-woman-shrugging-with-her-hands-in-the-air-16416649.jpg 「俺は何にも知らないよ」って言ってるので・・・

Comment: この著者は日本人のように本を書いた。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like he's suggesting that this character is holding his hands up in that half-shrugging "I don't know nothin'!" kind of way

Forgive the meme but this is the only picture that popped up in my 15 seconds of intense google imaging:

[image]

Whether or not this is 外国人のくせ I don't know, but that's what came to mind for me. Reading over it again I don't think the emotional quality of it is the same but I think the general gesture could be the same.

Either that or the author has his own idea of how foreigners act.

Edit: I'd like to comment that Chocolate's suggestion (from the position of a native speaker) of a pure [shrug](http://www.cavstheblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/searching.jpeg) may be accurate here, although apparently none of us as foreigners immediately associate shrugging with raising of the *hands* as much as we do with shoulders. However Japanese does have the word 肩をすくめる to refer to shrugging the shoulders. Seems to be a distinction between which way the palms are facing!

Either way the following image describes my feelings adequately.

[image]

Comment: This is what came to my mind. That or a wide-armed shrug.

Comment: Yes I read it. Anyway, looking at Chocolate's comment above I'd be inclined to agree more toward this gesture as a shrugging type thing. I guess I just don't associate shrugging with raising of the hands as much as I do with shoulders.